# Commerce Product Title translation in views

Tags: views, commerce

So i have [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) working properly on the actual products, but in the views displaying a list of these products translation just does not work.

1. [Entity traslation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) is enabled
2. [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module is enabled and configured

[image]

3. View advanced options configured correctly (won't let me add another pic
4. The actual custom text that displays in the list

[image]

yet in the list the products only display in the original language (greek) and not in the translated english one. Any idea what I might have configured wrong? Anything else I should add?